# Platform exception while using google cloud function in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions

I am making an app using firebase cloud function but every time I use it there is an exceptions

**index.js**

```
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and setup triggers.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Cloud Firestore.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.addUser = functions(region:'asia-south1').https.onCall((data, context) => {
    const users = admin.firestore().collection('log');
    return users.add({
       /* name: data["name"],
        email: data["email"]*/
        description: "test"
    });
});
```

and this is the function

```
final HttpsCallable callable= new CloudFunctions(region:"asia-south1" ).getHttpsCallable(
                    functionName: "addUser",


                );

                await callable.call().catchError((e)=>print(e));
```

and this is the exception
**PlatformException(functionsError, Cloud function failed with exception., {code: NOT_FOUND, details: null, message: NOT_FOUND})**

Comment: Are you sure you've deployed your cloud function?

Comment: Firebase CLI is at the latest version? Did you try to delete the function and redeploy it again?

Comment: This is the third I am doing so, every time I do it shows platform exception. One more request does anyone have a sample app or a recent docs.